# Lightning community maintenance page

Tags: community

I have tried to create a static resource for maintenance as per this [this](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_custom_sna_page.htm&type=5).

Then I assigned the static resource to **Service not available** page in the community. Then deactivated the community. Now when I navigate to the community, it shows empty white page instead of the maintenance page.

Any ideas what I am missing here.

Further more [this](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sites_error_pages.htm&type=5) doc explains that error pages are only applied to http requests. Our community is set to use https in session configuration. Is this the issue here?